# Run a for loop in R to calculate monthly mean from an Excel sheet

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, for-loop

I want to calculate the seasonal mean from monthly long-time temperature data.

```
series<-data$Temperature
p=5
new=NULL
for(i in 1:length){
  ydata<-series[((i-1)*p+1):(i*p)]
  yavg<-mean(ydata)
  new=rbind(new,yavg)
}
```

this is the loop expression I have for annual average, how should I change the expression to calculate the mean from May to September every month corresponding the observation no 5-9, 17-21......and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand how your data is structured (you haven't provided a sample of your data or a reprex). But from what I understand you want to calculate for each year the average temperature from May to September and beyond. In R it is better to do this with tools other than the for loop. Below is a proposed solution. I assume you have two columns in your data frame - date and temperature.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> (...)

set.seed(1900) # creating dummy data for two consecutive years
dates = seq(dmy(01012020), dmy(31122021), by = 1)
temperature = runif(length(dates), -10, +30)

df = tibble(dates, temperature)

df %>% 
  group_by(year = year(dates), month = month(dates)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(temperature)) %>% 
  print(n = Inf)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 24 × 3
#> # Groups:   year [2]
#>     year month mean_temp
#>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1  2020     1      7.86
#>  2  2020     2      9.70
#>  3  2020     3      9.00
#>  4  2020     4     11.9 
#>  5  2020     5     10.9 
#>  6  2020     6      7.44
#>  7  2020     7      4.45
#>  8  2020     8     10.9 
#>  9  2020     9     10.6 
#> 10  2020    10      9.85
#> 11  2020    11     13.2 
#> 12  2020    12     11.8 
#> 13  2021     1     11.3 
#> 14  2021     2      9.25
#> 15  2021     3      9.06
#> 16  2021     4      8.66
#> 17  2021     5     11.9 
#> 18  2021     6      8.03
#> 19  2021     7     11.6 
#> 20  2021     8     11.4 
#> 21  2021     9      8.55
#> 22  2021    10      8.95
#> 23  2021    11      9.00
#> 24  2021    12     11.5


df %>% 
  mutate(may_to_september = if_else(month(dates) %in% 5:9, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  group_by(year = year(dates), may_to_september) %>% 
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(temperature))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   year [2]
#>    year may_to_september mean_temp
#>   <dbl> <lgl>                <dbl>
#> 1  2020 FALSE                10.5 
#> 2  2020 TRUE                  8.86
#> 3  2021 FALSE                 9.69
#> 4  2021 TRUE                 10.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Below is an updated solution after describing the data by the questioner. Note that the average of the monthly averages is not the average of the raw data (measured daily).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> (...)

set.seed(1900)
Year <- rep(2020:2021, each= 12)
Month <- rep(1:12, times = 2)
temperature = runif(length(Month), -10, +30)

df <-  tibble(Year, Month, temperature)

df %>% 
  mutate(may_to_september = if_else(Month %in% 5:9, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, may_to_september) %>% 
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(temperature))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Year'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   Year [2]
#>    Year may_to_september mean_temp
#>   <int> <lgl>                <dbl>
#> 1  2020 FALSE                 4.73
#> 2  2020 TRUE                 10.5 
#> 3  2021 FALSE                12.3 
#> 4  2021 TRUE                  5.54
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I have Year, Month (as numbers 1,2,3...), and Temperature columns.

Comment: Thank you for the information on the data structure. I supplemented the answer with a proposed solution. See the contents of the variable `df` and confirm that your data has this structure.

Comment: Yes, similar structure.